# The "more" links at the bottom have the wrong number in parentheses

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, footer

The "more" links at the bottom of the page on the [main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) appear to have incorrect numbers next to them in parentheses.   As you can see from the following screenshot, the *Technology* section shows 21 sites along with "more (14)", so that indicates a total of 35 technology sites.  But when I click on "[more (14)](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic)", there are 49 technology sites listed.  The "more" links under the *Life/Arts*, *Culture/Recreation*, and *Science* sections have the same issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How odd. Let me investigate.

Comment: @Haney at first I thought it's not counting sites in Beta, but the numbers proved me wrong. Good luck!

Comment: It's a combination of things it looks like, involving public beta status as well as case-insensitive string comparisons. :)

Comment: @Haney oh wow, naSty stuFf... so [meta-tag:working-on-our-problemz]?